# Python pandas: map and return Nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frame, the first one is:

```
id code
1   2
2   3
3   3
4   1
```

and the second one is:

```
id code  name
1    1   Mary
2    2   Ben
3    3   John
```

I would like to map the data frame 1 so that it looks like:

```
id code  name
1   2    Ben
2   3    John
3   3    John
4   1    Mary
```

I try to use this code:

```
mapping = dict(df2[['code','name']].values)
df1['name'] = df1['code'].map(mapping)
```

My mapping is correct, but the mapping value are all NAN:

```
mapping = {1:"Mary", 2:"Ben", 3:"John"}

id code  name
1   2    NaN
2   3    NaN
3   3    NaN
4   1    NaN
```

Can anyone know why an how to solve?

Comment: Whats the dtype of code column

Comment: why not use merge: `df.merge(df2[['code','name']],on='code')`

Comment: @Chris - One possible reason is performance :)

Comment: @jezrael good point using map is like 4 times faster than merge

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem is different type of values in column `code` so necessary converting to integers or strings by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) for same types in both:

```
print (df1['code'].dtype)
object

print (df2['code'].dtype)
int64
```

```
print (type(df1.loc[0, 'code']))
<class 'str'>

print (type(df2.loc[0, 'code']))
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

---

```
mapping = dict(df2[['code','name']].values)
#same dtypes - integers
df1['name'] = df1['code'].astype(int).map(mapping)
```

```
#same dtypes - object (obviously strings)
df2['code'] = df2['code'].astype(str)
mapping = dict(df2[['code','name']].values)
df1['name'] = df1['code'].map(mapping)
```

---

```
print (df1)
   id code  name
0   1    2   Ben
1   2    3  John
2   3    3  John
3   4    1  Mary
```

Comment: Exactly what I thought

Comment: I tried to use `astype()`  but it still doesn't work:(

Comment: @LAMHeiHung - Maybe some trailing whitespaces? What return `print (df1['code'].head().tolist())` ?

Comment: @jezrael - the list is `['2', '3', '3', '1']`

Comment: @LAMHeiHung - and `print (df2['code'].head().tolist())` ?

Comment: @jezrael - you are correct! I didn’t change the data type first and it’s work! Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

Alternate way is using `dataframe.merge`

```
df.merge(df2.drop(['id'],1), how='left', on=['code'])
```

Output:

```
    id  code   name
0   1   2      Ben
1   2   3      John
2   3   3      John
3   4   1      Mery
```